# Incorporate known data moments into GPFlow fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow

I have recently been working with gpflow, in-particular Gaussian process regression, to model a process for which I have access to approximated moments for each input. I have a vector of input values X of size (N,1) and a vector of responses Y of size (N,1). However, I also know, for each (x,y) pair, an approximation of the associated variance, skewness, kurtosis and so on for the particular y value.

From this, I know properties that inform me of appropriate likelihoods to use for each data point.
In the simplest case, I just assume all likelihoods are Gaussian, and specify the variance at each point. I've created a minimal example of my code by adapting the tutorial on: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/varying_noise.ipynb#Demo-2:-grouped-noise-variances.

```
import numpy as np
import gpflow 

def generate_data(N=100):
    X = np.random.rand(N)[:, None] * 10 - 5  # Inputs, shape N x 1
    F = 2.5 * np.sin(6 * X) + np.cos(3 * X)  # Mean function values
    groups = np.arange( 0, N, 1 ).reshape(-1,1)  
    NoiseVar = np.array([i/100.0 for i in range(N)])[groups]  
    Y = F + np.random.randn(N, 1) * np.sqrt(NoiseVar)  # Noisy data
    return X, Y, groups, NoiseVar

# Get data
X, Y, groups, NoiseVar = generate_data()
Y_data = np.hstack([Y, groups])
# Generate one likelihood per data-point
likelihood = gpflow.likelihoods.SwitchedLikelihood( [gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(variance=NoiseVar[i]) for i in range(Y.shape[0])])

# model construction (notice that num_latent is 1)
kern  = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(input_dim=1, lengthscales=0.5)
model = gpflow.models.VGP(X, Y_data, kern=kern, likelihood=likelihood, num_latent=1)
# Specify the likelihood as non-trainable
model.likelihood.set_trainable(False)

# build the natural gradients optimiser
natgrad_optimizer = gpflow.training.NatGradOptimizer(gamma=1.)
natgrad_tensor    = natgrad_optimizer.make_optimize_tensor(model, var_list=[(model.q_mu, model.q_sqrt)])
session = model.enquire_session()
session.run(natgrad_tensor)
# update the cache of the variational parameters in the current session
model.anchor(session)

# Stop Adam from optimising the variational parameters
model.q_mu.trainable   = False
model.q_sqrt.trainable = False
# Create Adam tensor
adam_tensor = gpflow.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).make_optimize_tensor(model)
for i in range(200): 
    session.run(natgrad_tensor)
    session.run(adam_tensor)
# update the cache of the parameters in the current session
model.anchor(session)
print(model)
```

The above code works for a gaussian likelihood, and known variances. Inspecting my real data, I see that it is skewed very often and as a result, I want to use non-gaussian likelihoods to model it, but am unsure how to specify these other likelihood parameters given what I know.

So my question is: Given this setup, how can I adapt my code so far to include non-Gaussian likelihoods at each step, in-particular specifying and fixing their parameters based on my known variances, skewness, kurtosis and so on associated with each individual y value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to choose which non-Gaussian likelihood you use. GPflow includes various ones in `likelihoods.py`. You then need to adapt the line

```
likelihood = gpflow.likelihoods.SwitchedLikelihood(
    [gpflow.likelihoods.Gaussian(variance=NoiseVar[i]) for i in range(Y.shape[0])]
)
```

to give a list of your non-Gaussian likelihoods.

Which likelihood can take advantage of your skewness and kurtosis information is a statistical question. Depending on what you come up with, you may need to implement your own likelihood class, which can be done by inheriting from `Likelihood`. You should be able to follow some other examples from `likelihoods.py`.